# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de usar el método clone para copiar una lista en Java?

Tags: java, lista

Quiero copiar una lista en Java, y encontré un método llamado `clone`, el cual sirve para eso, y funciona bien, pero creo que no lo estoy usando correctamente, ya que me sale una advertencia en *Eclipse*.

Lo que hago es crear una lista, le agrego un entero, y por último uso el método para copiar.

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(5);
ArrayList<Integer> listaCopiada = (ArrayList<Integer>) lista.clone();
```

Al parecer había un problema, el método devuelve un `Object`, por lo que tuve que castearlo, y al hacer esto, me funciona, pero me sale una advertencia.

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<Integer>

Yo puedo dar click a la advertencia y ver múltiples soluciones, pero ninguna me convence.

**Extract to local variable:**

Esto duplica la línea, y entonces me sale otra advertencia del mismo tipo.

```
ArrayList<Integer> clone = (ArrayList<Integer>) lista.clone();
ArrayList<Integer> clone2 = clone;
ArrayList<Integer> clone1 = clone2;
ArrayList<Integer> clone21 = clone1;
ArrayList<Integer> clone11 = clone21;
```

**Extract to method:**

Esto me hace una función privada, que adentro tiene una línea con la misma advertencia.

```
ArrayList<Integer> listaCopiada = extracted(lista);
private static ArrayList<Integer> extracted(ArrayList<Integer> lista) {
    return (ArrayList<Integer>) lista.clone();
}
```

Cuando intento solucionar esa advertencia, me queda una función recursiva, lo cual me parece bastante ilógico, ya que quita la parte de clonar.

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> extracted1(ArrayList<Integer> lista) {
    return extracted1(lista);
}
```

**Add parentheses around cast:**

Esto me agrega unos paréntesis sin sentido, y sigue la advertencia.

```
ArrayList<Integer> listaCopiada = ((ArrayList<Integer>) lista.clone());
```

La sugerencia que recibo es **Remove extra parentheses**, esto es volver a como estaba antes.

**Add SupressWarnings 'unchecked':**

Esto me obliga a usar un comentario al código, diciendo que no me tire la advertencia. Esta es la única manera de que no me salga más la advertencia, pero creo que queda feo.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

¿Hay alguna manera (si es posible la oficial o correcta) de usar `clone` sin que salgan advertencias de este tipo?

Comment: Sobre el uso del método `clone`, véase "Item 11: Override clone judiciously" en el libro *Effective Java (2nd Edition)* de Joshua Bloch. También puede ser interés "2.3 Wildcards with super" y "8.4 Maintain Binary Compatibility" en el libro *Java Generics and Collections* de Maurice Naftalin y Philip Wadler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo evitaría usar el `clone`. Si quieres copiar la lista, simplemente puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lista.add(5);
ArrayList<Integer> listaCopiada = new ArrayList<Integer>(lista);
```

Answer (score 7):

Sobre el warning, la única manera de elimintarlo es usando la anotación `@SupressWarnings`. Esto sucede porque estás haciendo un casteo a un tipo genérico. En Java, no existe otra manera de hacer casteo hacia abajo a un objeto definido con genéricos (en este caso, de `Object` a `ArrayList<Integer>`) y eliminar la advertencia. No tiene nada de malo en usar `@SupressWarnings`, siempre y cuando sepas lo que estás haciendo. En caso que removieses el genérico, te saldría otro warning de uso de variables crudas (raw type), y de todas maneras tendrías que agregar esta anotación.

---

El método `clone` es un pobre intento de Java para implementar el patrón [prototype](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)). Digo que es pobre porque técnicamente no ofrece mucho valor y solo es una copia superficial. Solo hay pocos casos donde se debería llamar al método clone, como en un arreglo.

Para tu caso, si solo quieres una copia superficial con una nueva lista con los mismos objetos, es decir, que si modificas el estado de uno los objetos de la nueva lista también se verá el cambio de estado en la lista original (porque son el mismo objeto), entonces basta con lo siguiente:

```
List<Integer> copia = new ArrayList<>(listaOrigen);
```

Si lo que buscas es una copia profunda, es decir, que incluso los objetos en la nueva lista sean **diferentes** a los de la original y cada uno mantenga su propio estado, deberás asegurarte que cada elemento dentro de tu lista original sea inmutable o que implementen su propio método de clonado profundo como constructor de copia, serialización/deserialización u otro.

Answer (score 2):

No hay formas de eliminar el warning que no sea deshabilitando ese tipo de mensajes.

`clone` te va a devolver un elemento de tipo `Object` y eso es algo que no vas a poder modificar.

La alternativa es dejar de usar `clone` y hacer una copia del objeto usando el constructor copia:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listaCopiada =  new ArrayList<Integer>(lista);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la clase [`java.util.Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html):

```
List<String> listaCopia = new ArrayList<String>(listaOriginal.size());
Collections.copy(listaCopia, listaOriginal);
```

o el método más común:

```
List<String> listaCopia = new ArrayList<String>(listaOriginal);
```